# OverlaidXYPlotDemo1 : Changing Series Color

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have managed to change the color of the bars in [the OverlaidXYPlotDemo1](http://code.google.com/p/swing-ui-hxzon/source/browse/trunk/jfreechart/org/jfree/chart/demo/OverlaidXYPlotDemo1.java?spec=svn65&r=65), with :

```
XYItemRenderer xir = plot.getRenderer();
xir.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.BLUE);
```

However, I can´t change the color of the second series with

```
xir.setSeriesPaint(1, Color.GREY);
```

so I´m probably missing something. Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The correct way to do this, is using the renderers:

```
renderer1.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.YELLOW);
renderer2.setSeriesPaint(0, Color.GREY);
```